# How to use sed to find the line and its following line

Tags: sed

I would like to get the lines which begin with "Xboy" and its following lines which begins with "+". How can I do this by using sed?

The input looks like below:

```
Xapple

+apple1

+apple2

.ends

Xboy

+boy1

+boy2

V2

Xcat

+cat1

+cat2

Xcat
```

The output should look like below:

```
Xboy

+boy1

+boy2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job in `sed`, but really this problem is more complicated than `sed` is intended for. You'd be better off using `perl` or `python`.

```
$ cat foo.txt
Xapple
+apple1
+apple2
.ends
Xboy
+boy1
+boy2
V2
Xcat
+cat1
+cat2
Xcat
$ sed ':section;/Xboy/!d;:plusline;n;/^+/b plusline;b section' foo.txt
Xboy
+boy1
+boy2
```

In a proper programming language, the nested loop structure of the data becomes clearer, and we can be more confident there are no edge cases we've forgotten about.

In Perl:

```
my $line = <>;
while (defined($line)) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line eq "Xboy") {
        print $line, "\n";
        $line = <>;
        while (defined($line) && $line =~ /^\+/) {
            print $line;
            $line = <>;
        }
    }
    else {
        $line = <>;
    }
}
```

In Python:

```
import fileinput

lines = fileinput.input()

line = lines.readline()
while line != '':
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line == 'Xboy':
        print(line)
        line = lines.readline()
        while line != '' and line.startswith('+'):
            print(line, end='')
            line = lines.readline()
    else:
        line = lines.readline()
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the `sed` form from @potong's answer as it was far clearer and more general than mine!

Comment: And updated again to remove the `-n` and the block syntax

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk '/Xboy/ {f=1;print;next} {/^+/?a=1:f=0} a&&f' file
Xboy
+boy1
+boy2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;/Xboy/{:b;p;n;/^+/bb;ba}' file
```

If a line contains `Xboy`, print it and any following lines that begin `+` otherwise be silent.

I guessed this is what you intended, however you may have meant that other lines beginning with non-word-like characters should also be ignored, use:

```
sed -n ':a;/Xboy/{:b;p;:c;n;/^+/bb;/^\W/bc;ba}' file
```

or perhaps you meant this:

```
sed -n ':a;/Xboy/{:b;p;:c;n;/^+/bb;/^[^[:upper:]]/bc;ba}' file
```

It may be that you only want to print `Xboy` if there is a line following that begins `+`, then use:

```
sed -n ':a;/Xboy/{$d;h;:b;n;/^+/{H;$!bb};x;/\n/p;x;ba}' file
```